# Left slide in animation on entire list when new item is added to the list

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

On increment in `counts`, I want to smoothly transition entire list to go left to default position when new count is added. For now this is only appearing for one particular `count` that is being added.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-dream-n4pm38?file=/src/index.js)

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [counts, setCounts] = React.useState([1]);

  const increment = () => {
    const value = counts.length + 1;
    setCounts((prevState) => [...prevState, value]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      <div className="wrapper">
        {counts.map((count) => {
          return <p key={count}>{count}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper > p {
  animation: slideIn 400ms ease;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    left: 20px;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```